# Как исправить несовместимость библиотек Spring?? Spring не может инициализировать бин репозитория

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

Имею проект, где использую Spring Boot и Spring Data.
При компиляции получаю ошибку (Спринг не можеть создать бин UserRepository из-за ошибки java.lang.AbstractMethodError).
4-й день ищу решение в интернете, но так и не нашел.
У многих такая ошибка, но некоторые решения, которые я нашел, мне не помогли.
На одном форуме указали на возможную несовместимость некоторых библиотек,
но эту ошибку я также, к сожалению, не смог найти и исправить (т.к. не указываю явно версии библиотек).
Прошу помощи здесь.
Файл мейвена pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>root</groupId>
<artifactId>CourseWork5</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>coursework</name>
<description>empty</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ошибка

> 2017-01-24 13:03:14.538  WARN 13108 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>   2017-01-24 13:03:14.539  INFO 13108 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   2017-01-24 13:03:14.552  INFO 13108 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2017-01-24 13:03:14.572  WARN 13108 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
>   2017-01-24 13:03:14.594 ERROR 13108 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]     at
>   root.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:10) [classes/:na]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_65]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_65]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_65]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_65]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   ... 24 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   ... 37 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:280)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.3.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   ... 47 common frames
>   omitted

П.С. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767991/error-creating-bean-with-name-repository), если надо, вопрос с исходным текстом некоторых файлов.

Comment: Что внутри AddressRepository?

Comment: @NickSavenia спасибо. Проблема решилась пересозданием проекта..